# Can I render inline image in GitHub without link?

Tags: github, images

Is it possible to show image in GitHub markdown without it automatically wrapping it in a link to "full version"?

It does so even for small icons and logos, which is rather annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Best answer I could come up with is wrapping the image in

```
<a></a>
```

which besides having an additional DOM element works great.

Edit: `<a href="#"></a>` works as well but the image retains `cursor: pointer`.

Comment: with `a` tag, it has link to raw image, and with `href="#"` attribute it point to the beginning of the page. not a good solution for me.